# Pandas Dataframe- converting groupby contents to a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a big data frame and I am not showing here. I have performed following groupby operation on first column `group` of it and gave following result.

```
print(df.groupby(df['group']).count())
```

Result:

```
          group   current  voltage   FF  Ipmax  Isc  Pmax  Voc  Vpmax

         8157_S1       315      315  315    315  315   315  315    315

         8157_S2       312      312  312    312  312   312  312    312

         S_1.M_01      316      316  316    316  316   316  316    316

         S_1.M_02      315      315  315    315  315   315  315    315

         S_1.M_03      315      315  315    315  315   315  315    315

         S_1.M_04      315      315  315    315  315   315  315    315

         S_1.M_05      314      314  314    314  314   314  314    314
```

How do I convert contents in `group` column in above result to a list? Finally I want something like

```
         modules_list = [8157_s1, 8157_s2, S_1.M_01, .....]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get list of contents of group column you can simply use `print(list(df['group']))`.
I hope this may help you...